# How to do this curl request in Pure Javascript with parameter "-F"

Tags: javascript, file, post, upload

I want to use this API in `javascript/jquery`, which is currently in `curl` and get the JSON response, My below

```
curl -F "file=@test.txt" https://api.anonfiles.com/upload
```

## What i have tried

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://api.anonfiles.com/v1/upload" method="POST"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" /> 
    Send this file: <input name="file" type="file" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" /> 
</form>
```

(not working :/)

Comment: ​v​1​?​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​--------

Comment: ? :)
 @user202729

Comment: @Rémy Not js, in this case the op want to use HTML form.

Comment: @safoxot860 You have v1 in one of the URLbut not in the other.

Comment: @user202729 no, i really wants to use js, i just tried html form which didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.